# I am getting error ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. on paho-mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I am getting this error and i dont know what to do on python paho-mqtt

I was trying to connect on paho-mqtt using a basic script

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client = mqtt.Client("Clientus")
client.connect("localhost",1883,60)
```

Comment: server is not running at all or its not running in the given port  or firewaill is blocking connection. 0% you can do on your client/python side ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.